# Can uv light cause heterolytic cleavage?

Tags: physical-chemistry, bond, ions, radicals

All sources I've read stated that UV-light can only cause homolytic cleavage (homolytic fission), producing radicals while not mentioning whether it was possible for it to cause heterolytic cleavage instead. Hence is it possible for UV-light to result in heterolytic bond cleavage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a matter of energy of a single photon. Heterolytic cleavage of a symmetric bond requires more energy and can be less brobable, but see the [totalitarian principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totalitarian_principle).

E.g. the extreme UV (tens of eV per photon) can indiscriminately cleave any chemical bond both homolytically and heterolytically.

Comment: I agree (+1). However I would note in the arena of photolysis, there appears to be an element of selectivity which may be a little more complex than just an energy argument.